# How to start another Activity when you have the Activity name String but not the Activity.Class?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, package-managers

I'm running into a problem starting other activities from mine. I know this must be being done elsewhere as there are so many launcher apps out there which much use package manager to start specific activities...

I can get an Acitivity name I would like to start from the package manager, but how can I somehow parse this and turn it into an intent? Baring in mind I can't access the class... Also I would like to start that specific activity and not launch the MAIN intent from the package...

I'm sure someone must be doing this somewhere... It's kind of the point in activities isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setClassName(String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on the Intent to avoid needing the other class.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have following in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <!-- The askUser dialog activity -->
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:name="my.app.AskUserActivity" 
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.app.intents.AskUserConfirmConnect"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then you can call this Activity by name, like this:

```
Intent dlgIntent = null;

dlgIntent = new Intent("my.app.intents.AskUserConfirmConnect");
dlgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
dlgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
context.startActivity(dlgIntent);
```